# How to use grid loading animation script for my CSS grid (GridLoaderFx)

Tags: jquery, css, grid, css-animations

I'm trying to use 'grid loading animations' from http://yanshi.sucaihuo.com/jquery/17/1725/demo/

My grid is not built with jQuery, but I used CSS only. I'd love to use one of these animations for my grid. In the demo the animations only play when you click on an effect.

What I need is that the images are loaded immediately, while using one of these animations (preferably 'Shu'). I can't find an example on the demo site or github on how to achieve this. Is it also possible that the animations load on scroll? I use scrollreveal.js on my site.

Help would be really appreciated

https://codepen.io/Jaxxie/pen/pKKjPG

```css
/* ---- grid ---- */

img.grid__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(280px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #929796;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #424242;
  }
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-3 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-4 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.span-5 {
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.grid--hidden {
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.js .grid--loading::before,
.js .grid--loading::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1000;
}

.js .grid--loading::before {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #2c2d31;
}

.js .grid--loading::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(25vh - 20px);
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
  border: 8px solid #383a41;
  border-bottom-color: #565963;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animLoader 0.8s linear forwards infinite;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
  <script>
    document.documentElement.className = 'js';
  </script>
</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="grid grid-layout">
    <div class="grid-item span-5 grid-item-1"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item span-4 grid-item-3"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item span-2 grid-item-5"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item-6"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item-7"><img class="grid__img" src="https://www.dierendokters.com/images/Katten/kitten.jpg" alt="Some image" /></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://yanshi.sucaihuo.com/jquery/17/1725/demo/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://yanshi.sucaihuo.com/jquery/17/1725/demo/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://yanshi.sucaihuo.com/jquery/17/1725/demo/js/anime.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://yanshi.sucaihuo.com/jquery/17/1725/demo/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without js. Simple css solution is to add loading gif image to
".grid-item{}" as a background image. So loader will be visible until the image load is complete.